# xcode navigationbar is not more visible after popover with button

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uinavigationbar, popover

I have created a popover in iphone view with a button inside to segue to another ViewController.
But all Viewcontroller after popOver have the navigationbar not anymore.

My project structure:

- NavigationController -> ViewController1 -> ViewController2(popOver) ->ViewController3

All connections are: "show",except from ViewController1 to ViewController2: "present as popover"
If i connect(show) directly from ViewController1->ViewController3, everything is fine...

Where can be the problem?

I used this tutorial:
http://richardallen.me/2014/11/28/popovers.html

ViewController1:

```
func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
        return UIModalPresentationStyle.None
    }

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "PopOverIdentifier" {
            let popoverViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! 
            popoverViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.ViewController2
            popoverViewController.popoverPresentationController!.delegate = self
        }
}
```

ViewController2
includes Pickerview and:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "toVC3" {

        var DestViewController : ViewController3 = segue.destinationViewController as!ViewController3
        DestViewController.passedUserID_target = selected_user
    }
}
```

Problem:

[image: problem]

Comment: You're not showing the code how you present vc3 from popover vc2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem (temporarily) with adding a new NavigationController to the ViewController3 with (Editor->EmbedIn->NavigationController) and add a back button to buttom of the layout.

The problem to segue data from VC1->VC3, i solved with defining a global Variable in VC3 and add a action Button (in VC2) with assigning the data to these created global variables.